# A new expression requires ()

Tags: c#

I am following some Microsoft tutorial and got a code like this but it doesn't work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] liczby = new int liczby[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9, 10 };

            Console.WriteLine(liczby[5]);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost: `int[] liczby = new int[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9, 10 };`

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not descriptive of what it *is* doing.  If you're getting an error, tell us what it is.  Otherwise tell us what its doing that you aren't expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line where you are instantiating the int array to be this:

```
int[] liczby = new int[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9, 10 };
```

This is simply a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] liczby = new int liczby[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9, 10 };
```

This line has a syntax error, replace with:

```
int[] liczby = new int[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9, 10 };
```